# No route matches [GET] "/simulations"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I am really new to this forum and to code in general :)

I am trying to create a little simulator in my ruby on rails app. 
I created a model that takes all the attributes to do the calculation and the final result of the simulation will be stored in an attribute of my User model.
The objective of the simulator: the user, a freelancer, enters all his enterprise infos, and gets to know at the end of the simulation, how many taxes he has to pay. 
I coded one of the possible path for now, in a "set_result" method for my Simulation class.

All the attributes for the simulation are asked to the user via a simple form_for in the view and then the result of the simulation is calculated according to the user inputs to the form.
my model looks like this :

```
class Simulation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  ACTIVITES = ["liberale", "commerciale ou industrielle", "artisanale"]
  YEAREXISTENCE = [1, 2, 3, 4]

  before_save :set_result

  validates :activity, presence: true, inclusion: { in: ACTIVITES }
  validates :year_existence, presence: true, inclusion: { in: YEAREXISTENCE }
  validates :reglementary, presence: true
  validates :accre, presence: true

  def set_result
    answer = params[:simulation]

    if answer[:activity] == "liberale" && answer[:year_existence] == 2 && answer[:accre]
      self.result = 0.12
    else
      self.result = 0.23
    end
  end
end
```

my controller :

```
class SimulationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_simulation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :set_tax_rate]

  def new
    @simulation = Simulation.new
  end

  def create
    binding.pry
    @simulation = Simulation.new(simulation_params)
    if @simulation.save
      render :show
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_simulation
    @simulation = Simulation.find(params[:id])
  end

  def simulation_params
    params.require(:simulation).permit(:activity, :user_id)
  end
end
```

and my view where I put the simple_form_for and asking all the attributes necessary to simulate the result.

```````````````
<div class="container">
<h1 class= "structure ml-5">simulation</h1>
</div>

<!-- <h1>votre tx : <%= @result %></h1> -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-5">
    <%= simple_form_for @simulation, root_path, method: :get do |f| %>

        <%= f.input :activity,
        label:"Quelle est votre catégorie d'activité ?",
        collection: Simulation::ACTIVITES,
        include_blank: true,
        as: :select %>

        <%= f.input :reglementary,
        label:"Est-ce une activité libérale règlementée ?",
        as: :boolean,
        include_blank: true,
        as: :select %>

        <%= f.input :year_existence,
        label:"Quel est l'âge de l'entreprise en année d'activité ?",
        collection: Simulation::YEAREXISTENCE,
        include_blank: true,
        as: :select %>

        <%= f.input :accre,
        label:"Avez-vous obtenu l'ACCRE lors de votre création d'entreprise ?",
        as: :boolean,
        include_blank: true,
        as: :select %>

      <%= f.submit "valider", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
``````````````

I tried to "binding.pry" to see if the form gets me to the create action from the controller but it seems that it does not. 
When I get to the route : "/simulations/new", i can enter infos, but when i submit I have the error : "No route matches [GET] "/simulations"". As is I was redirecting my user to the "index" of simulations, which I don't think I did in my code...

when I try to create a new simulation in my console by for example

simul = Simulation.new(activity: "liberale"...)
simul.user_id = User.last

and then, trying to create it in my db :

simul.save


I get this error :

"NameError: undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Simulation:0x00007fcb6ea6f5b8>
from /Users/mac/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:430:in `method_missing"

of course, I removed all the raise and binding.pry before trying it :)
anyone has an idea of what gets in the way of my simulation params ???
I am not sure of the "set_result" method and especially how I called the params for simulation... maybe that's the problem. I tried to see in my previous apps, and seems that I did the same though...
```````````````

Comment: Do you have `resources :simulations`  added to your `routes.rb`?

Comment: yes ! resources :simulations, only: [:new, :create, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy] in my routes

Comment: The form should use POST method, not GET if you are creating something. use `simple_form_for @simulation do |f|`, the helper takes care of the url and the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove "url" and "method" options in your simple_form call. Use as below

```
<%= simple_form_for @simulation do |f| %>
```

By default, simple_forms will use 'POST' http method for submitting the form.
In the error, I can see that it hits simulations/index endpoint because of 'GET' httpmethod.

'POST' of /simulations will hit the create action in the controller.
Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You miss `index` route in your `routes.rb`. It maps to `/simuations` path.

either need to add it to your list:

```
resources :simulations, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

or use the implicit "all REST routes":

```
resources :simulations
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply change it to

```
resources :simulations
```

or add `:index` to your list:

```
resources :simulations, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

You can also exclude ones for other scenarios (it will do all of them except that):

```
resources :simulations, except: [:destroy]
```

More on routing is here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: thanks for your answer. just did it. :) the problem seems to be somewhere else now... as in my "rails c", my create method for simulation does not work because of the params I think. because even in the index redirection after submitting the form, I have a "no method for nil class"

Comment: You probably need to change the route on your form to be the `simulation_create_path` and not the `root_path`. The method should also be `post`

Comment: It also says nil becaues you have no method called `def index` which sets `@simulations = Simulation.all`.

Comment: for the index method I have actually ! I added it when adding the route :) I am trying to redirect the path in my form

Answer (score 0):

@mrzasa 
thanks. I added all the resources just to test. and in the index, i wanted to have the attributes of my simulation, so :

index.html.erb

```
<p><%= @simulations.first.activity %></p>
<p><%= @simulations.first.accre %></p>
<p><%= @simulations.first.reglementary %></p>
<p><%= @simulations.first.year_existence %></p>
<h1><%= @simulations.first.result %></h1>
```

I end up with a "undefined method `activity' for nil:NilClass". My simulation is not created...
But in my create method in the controller I added also a redirection to the show of the simulation we just created in the new.

```
def create
    @simulation = Simulation.new(simulation_params)
    @simulation.user = current_user
    if @simulation.save
      redirect_to simulation_path(@simulation)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are the changes/corrections I tried to make in my code:

This is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @simulation, url: simulations_path, method: :get do |f| %>

        <%= f.input :activity,
        label:"Quelle est votre catégorie d'activité ?",
        collection: Simulation::ACTIVITES,
        value_method: :activity,
        as: :select %>

        <%= f.input :reglementary,
        label:"Est-ce une activité libérale règlementée ?",
        as: :boolean,
        value_method: :reglementary,
        as: :select %>

        <%= f.input :year_existence,
        label:"Quel est l'âge de l'entreprise en année d'activité ?",
        collection: Simulation::YEAREXISTENCE,
        include_blank: true,
        value_method: :year_existence,
        as: :select %>

        <%= f.input :accre,
        label:"Avez-vous obtenu l'ACCRE lors de votre création d'entreprise ?",
        as: :boolean,
        include_blank: true,
        value_method: :accre,
        as: :select %>

      <%= f.submit "valider", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

[image]

This is what I get when I submit it (the same result with method: `:post` or `:get` in the simple_form...)

[image]

The `params[:simulation][:activity]...` are here but the instance is not created...

Is it something wrong in my "before_save" method in the Simulation  model?

> simulation.rb

```
class Simulation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  ACTIVITES = ["liberale", "commerciale ou industrielle", "artisanale"]
  YEAREXISTENCE = [1, 2, 3, 4]

  before_save :set_result

  validates :activity, presence: true, inclusion: { in: ACTIVITES }
  validates :year_existence, presence: true, inclusion: { in: YEAREXISTENCE }
  validates :reglementary, presence: true
  validates :accre, presence: true

  def set_result
    raise
    if params[:simulation][:activity] == "liberale" && params[:simulation][:year_existence] == 2 && params[:simulation][:accre]
      self.result = 0.12
    else
      self.result = 0.23
    end
  end
end
```

or maybe in my "create method" in the controller...:

```
class SimulationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_simulation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :set_tax_rate]

  def new
    @simulation = Simulation.new
  end

  def create
    @simulation = Simulation.new(simulation_params)
    @simulation.user = current_user
    if @simulation.save
      render :index
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def index
    @simulations = Simulation.all
  end

  def edit
  end

  def show
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

  def set_simulation
    @simulation = Simulation.find(params[:id])
  end

  def simulation_params
    params.require(:simulation).permit(:activity, :reglementary, :accre, :year_existence, :user_id)
  end
end
```

I am lost right now